# Ink responsive email: Trouble with block-grid, need assistance

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design, padding, html-email

I have used your block-grid template with some customization to match an email concept in order to achieve a responsive design which could work across mobile and in desktop email clients. Technically the right column needs to shift under the first one on smaller screens. I also used your CSS inliner. It works well except for a small problem which is driving me crazy! On my iPhone 4S (v. 7.1.1) in Apple Mail the layout displays a fair amount of padding on the far right instead of extending the tables all the way across the screen. The header and the following block of tables are affected as well as if they would have a padding on the right. I have set the width to be 100% but it doesn't seem to work. I have changed the background color of table cells in the included code in order to see how the tables are defined too.

http://www.aetna.com/creativeservices/email/healthyapps/HAoffer_test3d_justTables_plain.html

Any, suggestions of why the tables are not expanding and misbehaving with extra padding?

Thank you for your feedback in advance. 
Attila

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your table with the class name of "apps" is still set to 315px, even in the smaller media queries. I believe setting that to 100% should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the note regarding the "apps" but the "header" is set to 100% width and it doesn't expand across either.

Comment: No offense, but your layout is pretty confusing and that makes trouble-shooting harder. It looks like you have placeholder images that are just red borders and it doesn't help to make clear where certain elements are. If it's not too much trouble, please use [this website](http://placehold.it/) to create your placeholders and I may be able to help you further.